# What is syntax for selector in CSS for next element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, siblings

If I have a header tag `<h1 class="hc-reform">title</h1>`

```
h1.hc-reform{
    float:left;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#0e73bb;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:10px 0px;
}
```

and after that I have a paragraph `<p>stuff here</p>`.

How can I ensure using CSS that every `<p>` tag that follows the `h1.hc-reform` to use: `clear:both;`

would that be:

```
h1.hc-reform > p{
     clear:both;
}
```

for some reason that's not working.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

This is called the [adjacent sibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) selector, and it is represented by a plus sign...

```
h1.hc-reform + p {
  clear:both;
}
```

Note: this is not supported in IE6 or older.

Comment: That would only select the `p` that comes just after `h1.hc-reform`. Then again it might be the only one that the `clear: both` needs to be applied on for it to work since it simply clears the `h1` float, so it's still a valid answer.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes you are correct, I mis-read the spec and deleted that comment because it was wrong.  This selector will only match the `p` that is immediately preceded by `h1.hc-reform` (with the same parent element, of course).

Comment: wow didn't know about the adjacent sibling selector. Nice, thanks!

Comment: ~ is a better selector in this case. Here a working JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dZAtt/

Comment: worth noting that this doesn't work if the first element has any children

Comment: Any polyfills for IE6? ;)

Comment: @DanielDewhurst  Peace be with you mate..!!

Answer (score 85):

You can use the [sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) `~`:

```
h1.hc-reform ~ p{
     clear:both;
}
```

This selects all the `p` elements that come after `.hc-reform`, not just the first one.

Comment: The IE bugs in the first link are obscure edge case stuff, which is probably why quirksmode overlooks them.

Answer (score 17):

no `>` is a child selector.

the one you want is `+`

so try `h1.hc-reform + p`

browser support isn't great

Comment: 2020: Browser support is great after ten years. Just a info for CSS novices.

Answer (score 11):

The `>` is a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). So if your HTML looks like this:

```
<h1 class="hc-reform">
    title
    <p>stuff here</p>
</h1>
```

... then that's your ticket.

But if your HTML looks like this:

```
<h1 class="hc-reform">
    title
</h1>
<p>stuff here</p>
```

Then you want the [adjacent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors):

```
h1.hc-reform + p{
     clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I sure hope he didn't nest p's inside h1's.. Also, adjacent only selects the first p.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. The `h1.hc-reform > p` means "any `p` exactly one level underneath `h1.hc-reform`".

What you want is `h1.hc-reform + p`. Of course, that might cause some issues in older versions of Internet Explorer; if you want to make the page compatible with older IEs, you'll be stuck with either adding a class manually to the paragraphs or using some JavaScript (in jQuery, for example, you could do something like `$('h1.hc-reform').next('p').addClass('first-paragraph')`).

More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html or http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/