# CSS selector, next tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<td>
<div class="m"><span class="a1">1 Puolimas</span></div>
<div class="d">po <span id="timer1">2:25:10</span></div>
</td>
```

How to select "2:25:10" with css selector if i can't use (span[id=timer1]) because id could be different.

I have tried:

```
span.a1 ~ span
```

But this selector do not work.

You could try here: http://jsfiddle.net/cSQcT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way using CSS to navigate from `a1` and get to `timer`. You cannot navigate backwards/up with CSS only downwards/adjacent. You'll need to use javascript or start from the top down like `.d > span`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
 .m + .d > span { color: blue; }
```

Also check this for the + selector: [CSS next element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660046/css-next-element)

However, you cannot go up one level (from the span.a1).
Your selector must start from the same or upper level.