# Style the p tag which is after a div(div not parent of p)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This may seem foolish.. I want to give style to a `p` tag which is after a certain `div`(the `div` is not the parent of the `p` tag).For example

```
<div>Hai</div>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>How are you?</p>
```

Here I want to give style to the `p` tags. I cant put these `p` tag in another `div`.I want to give all the `p` tags followed by the `div` same style.And also I cant give the style to `p` tag universally as it will affect other pages. Can anyone help? Hope I am clear with my question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660046/css-next-element help you how to handle next element vaia css

Comment: It will be easier to say if you can show your entire page code

Comment: The inherent underlying problem is that your HTML isn't structured correctly. If you correctly grouped content using `<article>`, `<section>` and `<header>` tags you wouldn't have the problem you're facing now.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes How is using article/section/header instead of div/p going to change anything.  You don't know what the div actually contains, it could contain an image gallery or used as a hook for multicolumn content for all you know.  If the content is dynamically generated, the tags likely cannot be changed.

Comment: @cinnamon the grouping of related content by semantics is what allows styling rules to be grouped. If you have to select 'all elements following a certain element' you should've put them in their own container to begin with, since they're obviously considered a group for *some* reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the general sibling selector :

```
div ~ p {
    color: red;
}
```

See this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yvdN6/4/.

You can see the [doc](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) :

> The elements don’t have to be adjacent siblings, but they have to have the same parent, and the `div` element has to occur before the `p` element in the document source.

Comment: Thank you very much... I wasn't aware that there are these kinds of methods too for selecting an element.Thanks a lot

Comment: Why on earth do you call it the adjacent sibling selector but then reference a quote that says the siblings don't have to be adjacent?

Comment: @BoltClock : yes sorry, I have typed a bit quick... I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

To select only the immediate `p` sibling:

```
div + p {
    color: peru;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvdN6/

Or to select *all* succeeding `p` siblings, use the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)

```
div ~ p {
color: peru;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvdN6/7/

Comment: I think that the OP want to style all next paragraphs and not only the following one as do your code...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie You got it...thats what I want

Comment: @Adrift You answer is also almost right. But it selects only the immediate `p` tag. But the answer that I accepted selects all the `p` tags after the div.

Answer (score -2):

```
<style type="text/css">
div + p{
Styles here
}
</style>
```

Comment: this would only style a `p` tag inside of the parent `div`

Comment: This will give all the `p` tags in every pages of the site right?

Comment: here `div` is not the parent of `p`