# Add class on sibling next to element

Tags: jquery

I have a list

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li class="active">2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

I need a jquery to add a class to one of active class siblings (prev or next sibling). This is a part of a navigation and active class it's the active page.
Can anyone help please?

Thank you!!

**UPDATE:
I found another way to add style to the next element from a list, with css: [CSS next element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660046/css-next-element)
Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S52YH/2/
Thank you for your effort!!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add class to previous `li`

```
$('li.active').prev().addClass("someclass");
```

Add class to next `li`

```
$('li.active').next().addClass("someclass");
```

Comment: this could help me but the class "someclass" is not moving. Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/S52YH/1/ the active class is moving from a li to another when clicked.

Comment: thank you but I found another way to do it:  UPDATE: I found another way to add style to the next element from a list, with css: CSS next element Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S52YH/2/ Thank you for your effort!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `li` elements for menu items. So there should be only one `active` classed element. If so,

```
var $activeElement = $(".active");

$( ".active" ).next().addClass( "active" );
$activeElement.removeClass("active");
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26Dfn/)

Answer (score 1):

[**Try this demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/S52YH/)

```
//  this will apply active class to all li
$('ul li').addClass('active');
//  this will apply particular index of child
$('ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.active').prev().addClass('foo');
```

or

```
$('.active').next().addClass('foo');
```