# How do I select the next item after a target element in css?

Tags: html, css

I have the follow:

```
<a name="a"></a><b>A</b>
```

I want to select the next item, the `<b>`, and highlight it when the target is selecting.
To select anything in the `a` tag I use: (for example)

```
[id]:target {background:pink;}
```

And that works. However, when I use this:

```
[id]:target + b {}
```

This doesn't work. Is this not possible with CSS?
I wish I could wrap the a tag around the item, but I don't have that option here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660046/css-next-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work, if you use the attribute "name" and then look for "id" in your CSS.

```css
[id]:target { background:pink; }
[id]:target + b { background:pink; }
```

```html
<a id="a">A</a>
<b>B</b>
<a href="#a">Turn pink!</a>
```

This turns both A and B pink (tested in Chrome / Firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Update your HTML to use ID's or update you CSS selectors to look for the `name` attribute:

```css
[name]:target {background:pink;}
[name]:target + b {background:blue; color:white;}
```

```html
<a href="#a">focus</a> | <a href="#">blur</a>
<br />
<a name="a">I am the A </a><b>I am the B</b>
```