# change property of div on hover of an image

Tags: html, css

```css
#myUserMenu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 20px;
  width: 116px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#myAvatar:hover #myUserMenu {
  background-color: red;
}
.menuItem {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

```html
<img id='myAvatar'>some text here...
<div id="myUserMenu">
  <div class='menuItem'>Status online</div>
  <div class='menuItem'>Status offline</div>
</div>
```

So when I hover the myAvatar, myUserMenu background should change to red

```
#myAvatar:hover #myUserMenu
```

And nothing happens ! Any idea why ?

Comment: Nothing happens because you are saying on hover on avatar to find inside another element (UserMenu) and there is no such element.

Comment: try: `#myAvatar:hover ~ #myUserMenu`

Comment: add a `+` in between your selectors.

Comment: If the element is outside of the hover element, it won't work.  I suggest using JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS next element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660046/css-next-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the text inside a span and use `+` operator to affect the next element's style.

```css
#myUserMenu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 20px;
  width: 116px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#myAvatar:hover + #myUserMenu {
  background-color: red;
}
.menuItem {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

```html
<span id="myAvatar">some text here...</span>
<div id="myUserMenu">
  <div class='menuItem'>Status online</div>
  <div class='menuItem'>Status offline</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#myAvatar:hover #myUserMenu {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This selector is looking for `#myUserMenu` *inside* `#myAvatar`. Obviously that won't work because it's outside `#myUserMenu`.

What you could do is look for `#myUserMenu` immediately after `#myAvatar`, like so:

```
#myAvatar:hover + #myUserMenu {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This is the Adjacent Sibling Combinator. See [this article for more details](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/).

Or you could rearrange your HTML to put `#myUserMenu` inside `#myAvatar`.

Answer (score 0):

Your div `#myUserMenu` is not a child of your image, so you need to target the div with a brother selector :

```
#myAvatar:hover ~ #myUserMenu {
    background-color:red;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/o0c2hppv/

The general sibling combinator selector `~` allow you to select the element which can appear anywhere after it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to apply parent child relationship in order to apply hover.

Like this

```css
#myUserMenu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 20px;
  width: 116px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;  
}
#myAvatar:hover #myUserMenu {
    background-color:red;
}

.menuItem {
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom:1px solid #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="myAvatar">
<img id=''> some text here...
    <div id="myUserMenu">
        <div class='menuItem'>Status online</div>
        <div class='menuItem'>Status offline</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "You can only change Child's property on hover of parent." Not true.