# Find the text nearest to an element in HTML content

Tags: php, jquery, html-content-extraction

I have an HTML content with specific tags which have text and images in it.
What if I am able to select an image and I want the the text nearest to an image?

```
<div class="topStory">
    <div class="photo">
    <a href="somelink"><img src="someimage.jpg" border="0" alt="Photo"></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="somelink">Text near to someimage.jpg</a></h2>
    <p>Some extra text.</p>
</div>
```

In this case I want the text nearest to someimage.jpg. Is it possible to achieve this using PHP? or may be jQuery?

Comment: have you used [search](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3660077/5397119) before asking ?

Comment: `$('img').closest('.topStory').find('p').text();`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was called out about giving the OP the wrong information and included 2 links about `.closet()` what am I not grasping? I guess probably I didn't include `.find()`?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Your thoughts on Jay's example?

Comment: `.closest()` looks for an ancestor or parent. To get from the image to its related text requires going up (closest) and then down(find) as the image and text are not siblings of each other.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think this will be more generic if it was $('img').closest('div').find('p').text();. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It would be more generic, but it is wrong as the closest div, `.photo` is a *sibling* of the paragraph.

Comment: There's no magic pill, you have to know your HTML and traverse accordingly.

Comment: Just a thought. Is it possible using PHP to strip all tags except image tags and text content?

Comment: ...yes. `strip_tags()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php takes arguments/exclusions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm really sorry, I was inattentive. Next time I will more attentive.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo no worries. OP has enough to go on now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a minimum of DOM traversal you can select (click on) the image and find the text:

```
<div class="topStory">
    <div class="photo">
    <a href="somelink"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" border="0" alt="Photo"></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="somelink">Text near to someimage.jpg</a></h2>
    <p>Some extra text.</p>
</div>
```

jQuery ([get the sibling paragraph](http://jsfiddle.net/619vfak1/)) UP to `.photo` and ACROSS to `h2`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var associatedText = $(this).closest('.photo').siblings('h2').text();
  console.log(associatedText);
});
```

You can also go [further up the DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/619vfak1/1/) if need be. UP to `.topStory` and DOWN to `h2`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var associatedText = $(this).closest('.topStory').find('h2').text();
  console.log(associatedText);
});
```

Here is the jQuery documentation for each function demonstrated:

[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
[`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

**EDIT**: Based on a good catch by @guest271314 and a re-reading of the OP's question, I have changed `p` to `h2`.

Comment: _"In this case I want the text nearest to someimage.jpg. "_ Should `.find('p')` be `.find('h2')` ?

Comment: Yes - you would do that if that is the text you're looking for @guest271314

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.find()` to select `img` within `.topStory` parent element ; select parent of `img` element which is not `.topStory` ; select first element that is adjacent sibling to previously selected `img` parent element , call `.text()` on returned element

```js
var topStory = $(".topStory");
var img = topStory.find("img");
// here `img.parents().not(topStory)` is `context`
var text = $("~ *:first", img.parents().not(topStory)).text();
console.log(img, text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topStory">
    <div class="photo">
    <a href="somelink"><img src="someimage.jpg" border="0" alt="Photo"></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="somelink">Text near to someimage.jpg</a></h2>
    <p>Some extra text.</p>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3cvh5rk5/

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard See updated post. stacksnippets went down as was composing, will create a jsfiddle

Comment: @JayBlanchard Substituted `topStory` for `top` to not conflict with `window.top` . Is explanation provided for approach adequate ?

Comment: that looks much better.