# select div by class only if previous element in DOM with particular ID exists

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select a div and change its background image but only if the a element before it exists and has a certain ID. See the following:

```
<td class ="thumbnails">
<a name="abc" id ="def"></a>
<div class="bgimages"></div>
</td>
```

How would I select and change the background image of the div with class 'bgimages' based on whether or not it has the a element before it with the ID 'def'?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS next element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660046/css-next-element)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use jQuery or javascript for this, you can do with only CSS. See below example with colors.

```css
.bgimages {
    background-color: green;
}

#def + .bgimages {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class ="thumbnails">
      <a name="abc" id ="def">yyyy</a>
      <div class="bgimages">yyyy</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class ="thumbnails">
      <a name="abc" id ="defxxx">yyyy</a>
      <div class="bgimages">yyyy</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Replace `background-color` with `background-image`

Comment: Nice, people are too quick to jump to the jquery route

Answer (score 2):

You can select the `div` element with a `def` id anchor before as such;

```js
console.log($("a#def").next("div.bgimages"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class ="thumbnails">
<a name="abc" id ="def"></a>
<div class="bgimages"></div>
</td>
```