# How to select next div same level by using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have HTML structure like this :

```html
<div>
   <span id="author-comment-2">Author</span>
   <div>
     <div class="author">I don't want this text</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div>
   <span id="author-comment-3">Author</span>
   <div>
     <div class="author">I want this text</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div>
   <span id="author-comment-4">Author</span>
   <div>
     <div class="author">I don't want this text</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I just want the text **'I want this text'**. So how can I get it by using Puppeteer because it is don't have ID or Class that I can use to reference to it?

Thank you for advance answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is syntax for selector in CSS for next element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660046/what-is-syntax-for-selector-in-css-for-next-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
page.$eval('#author-comment-3 + div>.author', element => {
  return element.innerHTML
})
```